# My system always showing this problem

Tags: updates

**Hello,my system always showing this problem when i click software updater,
when i click software update this a problem window appears which asks me to report the problem.but when i click report this window keeps asking me again and keeps repeating**.

[image]

Comment: The reason it keeps asking is because the program is crashing repeatedly.  You'd have to hit "Show Details" and then show us what those details are, but when crashes like this happen Apport kicks in and asks if you want to send error reports.  Which Ubuntu version are you using, though?

Comment: If you click "Remember this in future" and "Send" it will go away and stop nagging you. The crash report will be uploaded, and it will automatically upload next time whatever it is crashes.